# How to implement water clipping plane in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shaderlab

https://youtu.be/0NH9k4zTAqk

I am using a camera for water reflection.

Is there a way to not render as height below the water level?

like the youtube video above.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](https://www.ronja-tutorials.com/post/021-plane-clipping/) should help you to do this into unity using surface shader